# Yii2: тонкости валидации при загрузке файлов

Tags: yii2

Стояла такая задача: **сделать обязательным выбор файла в форме**.

---

Прописав в правилах валидатор `required` вроде всё работает как предполагается:

```
[['file'], 'required'],

[['file'], 'file', 'maxFiles' => 5],
```

То есть на клиенте срабатывает как «обязательность выбора», так и «максимально допустимое количество файлов» и сервер всё пропускает.

---

Позже (бороздя просторы документации) я обнаружил в классе [yii\validators\Validator](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-validators-validator.html), от которого наследуются другие валидаторы, свойство [`$skipOnEmpty`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-validators-validator.html#$skipOnEmpty-detail):

> Whether this validation rule should be skipped if the attribute value is null or an empty string.
>
> Определяет будет ли текущее правило валидации пропущено если значение атрибута равно `null` или пустой строке.

Значение по умолчанию: `true`.

---

Читая документацию далее я обнаружил также свойство [`$uploadRequired`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-validators-filevalidator.html#$uploadRequired-detail), но уже именно в [`yii\validators\FileValidator`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-validators-filevalidator.html):

> The error message used when no file is uploaded. Note that this is the text of the validation error message. To make uploading files required, you have to set $skipOnEmpty to false.
>
> Это сообщение об ошибке используется когда файл загружен. Заметьте, что это текст сообщения ошибки валидации. Чтобы сделать файлы обязательными к загрузке, вы должны установить `$skipOnEmpty` в значение `false`.

---

Я попробовал использовать вместо валидатора `required` установку свойства `skipOnEmpty` в значение `false`:

```
//[['file'], 'required'],

[['file'], 'file', 'maxFiles' => 5, 'skipOnEmpty' => false],
```

Получилось, что на клиенте действительно файл становится обязательным к загрузке; **НО** после выбора файла и отправки формы, она не проходит валидацию по файлу: пишет, что типа файл не выбран (Please upload a file) ...

Почему так происходит: клиент требует выбрать — мы выбираем — клиент пропускает, а сервер говорит, что файл не выбран?

Ну и исходя из вышеспрошенного вопроса: правильно ли указывать обязательность загрузки файла при помощи валидатора `required`?

Answer (score 2):

Обязательность загрузки файла правильно указывать через 'skipOnEmpty' => false
когда у вас отсутствует правило maxFiles. Странное поведение, описанное вами, связанно именно с этим свойством, если его убрать то валидация пройдёт успешно. В случае если необходимо использовать правило maxFiles проверку обязательность нужно осущетсвлять через requried. [Подробнее про загрузку файлов на сервер](http://web-sprints.ru/yii2-zagruzka-faylov-i-izobrazheniy/)